# How do mongos instances work together in a cluster?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I'm trying to figure out how different instances of mongos server work together.

If I have 1 configserver and some shards, for example four, each of them composed by only one node (a master of course), and have four mongos server... do the mongos server communicate between them? Is it possible that one mongos redirect its load to another mongos?

Answer (score 8):

When you have multiple mongos instances, they do not automatically load-balance between each other. They don't even know about each others existence.

The MongoDB drivers for most programming languages allow to specify multiple mongos instances when creating a connection. In that case the driver will usually ping all of them and connect to the one with the lowest latency. This will usually be the one which is closest geographically. When all have the same network distance, the one which is least busy right now will usually respond first. The driver will then stay connected to that one mongos, unless the program explicitely reconnects or the mongos can no longer be reached (in that case the driver will usually automatically pick another one from the initial list).

That means using multiple mongos instances is normally only a valid method for scaling when you have a large number of low-load clients, not one high-load client. When you want your one high-load client to make use of many mongos instances, you need to implement this yourself by creating a separate connection to each mongos instance and implement your own mechanism to distribute queries among them.

Comment: The `mongos` servers provide a routing service to direct read/write queries to the appropriate shard(s). It's not a case of "usually not load balancing"; the `mongos` *never* load balances as at MongoDB 2.4. Any load balancing behaviour would have to be implemented through drivers as there is no server support. The typical behaviour is to have multiple `mongos` in your connect string for failover. Network latency is also unrelated to which `mongos` is "most busy"; the measure of *nearest* is "by ping time" (from the driver's point of view) and does not consider load.

Comment: @Stennie I updated my answer, but please keep in mind that when a server has a high CPU load and/or is suffering from network congestion it will take longer to respond to pings.

Answer (score 5):

#### Short answer

As of MongoDB 2.4, the `mongos` servers only provide a *routing service* to direct read/write queries to the appropriate shard(s). The `mongos` servers discover the configuration for your sharded cluster via the config servers. You can find out more details in the MongoDB documentation: [Sharded Cluster Query Routing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/).

#### Longer scoop

> I'm trying to figure out how different instances of mongos server work togheter.

The `mongos` servers do not currently talk directly to each other. They do coordinate activity some activity via your config servers:

- reading the sharded cluster metadata
- initiating a balancing round (any `mongos` can [start a balancing round](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/#cluster-balancer), but only one round can be active at a time)

> If I have 1 configserver

You should *always* have 3 config servers in production. If you somehow lose or corrupt your config server, you will have to combine your data and re-shard your database(s). The sharded cluster metadata saved on the config servers is the definitive source for what sharded data ranges should live on each shard.

> some shards, for example four, each of them composed by only one node (a master of course)

Ideally each shard should be backed by a replica set if you want optimal uptime. Replica sets provide for auto-failover and can be very useful for administrative purposes (for example, taking backups or adding indexes offline).

> Is it possible that one mongos redirect its load to another mongos?

No, the `mongos` do not perform any load balancing.  The typical recommendation is to deploy one `mongos` per app server.

From an application/driver point of view you can specify multiple `mongos` in your connect string for failover purposes. The application drivers will generally connect to the nearest available `mongos` (by network ping time), and attempt to reconnect to in the event the current `mongos` connection fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I ask if mongos can communicate each other because I'm testing MongoDB for my purpose (this is why I only have one config server and not replica!) and I'm using YCSB, that permit me to specify only one mongos server per client. So I have four client that connect to four different mongos, and I notice that one mongos works really hard and other none! Maybe it's caused by my shardkey. I have X million rows composed by rowkey (userXXXXXXXXXXX) that is also my shardkey, and for each row ten fields of strings

Comment: @user2867270 When one mongos works harder than the other then either its client is more demanding than the others or that mongos runs on slower hardware.

Comment: @user2867270: is the `mongos` that is working harder the first in your connect string? Perhaps it is handling more clients .. you could check in the `mongo` shell with `db.serverStatus().connections`. I would also suggest trying [achille's YCSB fork](https://github.com/achille/YCSB) which has contributions from several folks at MongoDB. There is also a relevant feature suggestion for the Java driver that you can upvote/watch: [JAVA-699: Add round robin support for mongos connection strings](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-699).

Comment: That command on my mongos returns me `db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 1, "available" : 818, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(181) }`. There are no a "connection string" (or maybe I don't understand :P ). I'm using YCSB classic version, if I have time I'll try the achielle's version, still I prefer use the classic one because I'm testing other databases and prefer to use the same tool for everyone.